# How can I separate log file?

Tags: matlab

I have a log file like this:

```
00:00.262   ID:1    info
00:00.268   ID:4    info
00:00.268   ID:6    info
00:00.268   ID:24   info
00:00.268   ID:17   info
00:00.268   ID:20   info
00:00.268   ID:13   info
00:00.268   ID:18   info
00:00.268   ID:14   info
00:00.268   ID:23   info
00:00.268   ID:19   info
(...)
```

so, i developed this algorithm to separate the log file in separate files, according to ID.

```
% Read file
Data = textscan(log_fileID, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n', 'whitespace', '');
CStr = Data{1};

% Create separate files 
for i = 1:1:number

    IndexC = strfind(CStr, sprintf('ID:%d', i));
    Index = find(~cellfun('isempty', IndexC)); %
    % Delete lines
    if ~isempty(Index)
     Aux = CStr(Index);
    end

    % Save the file
    savePath = './Node/'; % Save files directory
    FID = fopen([savePath sprintf('Node %d.0.txt', i)],'w'); 
    if FID == -1, error('Cannot open file'), end
    fprintf(FID, '%s\n', Aux{:});

    fclose(FID);   
end
```

However, i have a problem.

When i create a file to ID:1, are saved in the file all the lines that appears ID:1, ID:10 ,ID:11, ID:12, ..., ID:19.

How can i solve this problem with a simple way?
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [`str2num()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html). when you extract your ID tag in `IndexC`, try to *only* match the integer numerically.

Answer (score 0):

I used matlab's built in import tool to generate a function for importing your data into a table. This makes it much easier to manipulate. Assuming that you've loaded your log file into a variable called `test` you can use this minimal amount of code to write the `info` to a file named after its id. I've have not checked the code against instances of multiple id's having the same name so you may want to check that.
You should end up with text files named 'ID1.txt','ID2.txt' etc.

```
 function test = importfile(filename, dataLines)
%IMPORTFILE1 Import data from a text file
%  TEST = IMPORTFILE1(FILENAME) reads data from text file FILENAME for
%  the default selection.  Returns the data as a table.
%
%  TEST = IMPORTFILE1(FILE, DATALINES) reads data for the specified row
%  interval(s) of text file FILENAME. Specify DATALINES as a positive
%  scalar integer or a N-by-2 array of positive scalar integers for
%  dis-contiguous row intervals.
%
%  Example:
%  test = importfile1("path/to/file.txt", [1, Inf]);
%
%  See also READTABLE.
%
% Auto-generated by MATLAB on 25-Jul-2019 07:19:02

%% Input handling

% If dataLines is not specified, define defaults
if nargin < 2
    dataLines = [1, Inf];
end

%% Setup the Import Options
opts = delimitedTextImportOptions("NumVariables", 4);

% Specify range and delimiter
%opts.DataLines = [1, Inf];
opts.DataLines = dataLines;
opts.Delimiter = ["ID:","   "];

% Specify column names and types
opts.VariableNames = ["Time","IDNum",  "Info","Var4"];
opts.SelectedVariableNames = ["Time", "IDNum", "Info"];
opts.VariableTypes = ["char", "double", "char", "char"];
opts = setvaropts(opts, [1, 3, 4], "WhitespaceRule", "trim");
opts = setvaropts(opts, [1, 2, 3], "EmptyFieldRule", "auto");
opts.ExtraColumnsRule = "ignore";
opts.EmptyLineRule = "read";
opts.ConsecutiveDelimitersRule = "join";

% Import the data
test = readtable(filename, opts);

end
```

---

```
unq = unique(test.IDNum);
savePath = './Node/';
for i = 1:size(unq,1)
    fullPath = [savePath,'ID',char(num2str(test.IDNum(i))),'.txt'];
    %generate index for info
    idx = test.IDNum == unq(i);
    info = test.Info(idx);
    FID = fopen(fullPath,'w');
    fprintf(FID,'%s',info);
    fclose(FID);
end
```

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your help.
Your idea only has one problem.
In my log file, the timestamp can be in the format 00:00.268 (length = 9) or 10:00:00.268 (length = 12) our 110:00:00.268 (length = 13).
So, how can i adapt the code to read all the formats?
Can you help me, please? I really don't know.

Comment: Please check out the edited response. The code should now accommodate time stamps of length 12 and 13

Comment: hello again,
Thanks for your help.
Timestamp works perfectly now, however, I got this result:

         Time          IDNum    Info
    _________    _____    ____

    '58:27.241'         NaN      '' 
    '58:27.247'         NaN      '' 
    '1:58:27.250'       NaN      '' 
    '1:58:41.647'       NaN      '' 
    '1:58:41.655'       NaN      '' 
    '1:58:53.358'       NaN      '' 
    '1:58:53.364'       NaN      '' 
    '1:58:55.647'       NaN      '' 

What do I need to change?
id and info column is not completed.
Thank you for your support.